# Using vertex shader to move texture to pixel center

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I am trying to move my texture to the center of the pixel as stated here [OpenGL Texture Coordinates in Pixel Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879403/opengl-texture-coordinates-in-pixel-space/5879551#5879551) but am struggling to do so. Are the pixels we are trying to center on in the texture or on the screen? How do we access them? Here is my vertex shader:

```
"uniform mat4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTIONMATRIX + ";\n" +
"attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION + ";\n" +
"attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR + ";\n" +
"attribute vec2 " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +
"varying vec4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_COLOR + ";\n" +
"varying vec2 " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +

"void main() {\n" +
"   " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_COLOR + " = " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR + ";\n" +
"   " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + " = " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +
    "   gl_Position = " + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTIONMATRIX + " * " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION + ";\n" +
"}"
```

I am new to open GL and have just started doing research on vertex shaders, so any suggestion or tip would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The problem I experience, is that the pixels from my texture get deformed when scaled. Normal textures look fine, but when they are scaled using the scaleM command on the 4x4 Matrix (Model view matrix), then it looks like there are two columns or two rows of the same pixels in random rows and columns.

Comment: Can you give more of a background on what the actual problem is? I'm not sure why you think you need to do this in a vertex shader. If you just want to make sure that your texture gets sampled in the center of the texels, then I have an old post with a descriptive image that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11458037/1236185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the scale factor was causing the distortion. All I had to do was make sure that each pixel in the texture had the same amount of pixels on the display, and the distortions disappeared.